# Live Video Stream between two Android Phones

Tags: android, sockets, media-player, android-videoview

I am currently working on video streaming between two Android Phone. 
I wrote an application which is able to record the video to the sd file (Using MediaRecorder); and I wrote another application which is able to display the video of the file. Both applications work perfectly.

I found a website about "Broadcasting video with Android - without writing to local files" in following website. It is exactly what I wanted to do.

http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system

I modified my code.

For the video recorder, 
it is:

```
socket=severSocket.accept();
ParcelFileDescriptor=pfd;
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
recorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
recorder.prepare(); 
recorder.start();
```

For Video Player:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(IP,PORT);
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(pfd.getFileDescriptor()); // <-- here is the problem
mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder); 
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);            
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);            
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);            
mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Program crush on **`mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(pfd.getFileDescriptor());`** on MediaPlayer
I know I didnt setup the DataSource correctly. There must be additional setups for **ParcelFileDescriptor** to put into MediaPlayer.

Does anyone know how to use **ParcelFileDescriptor** for MediaPlayer?
Any helpful advise or tips would be nice......

Thank You

Will

Comment: is that working for you? if it is working ,plz tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: i would love to know if you figured this out too. i have exactly the same problem and the answer below doesn't help

Answer (score 4):

in the video playing side 
you must create a welcome socket

```
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
socket soc = welcomeSocket.accept();
```

and use

```
mMediaplayer.prepareAsync();
```

instead of

```
mMediaplayer.prepare();
```

Comment: hi, it seems you only set the port number, how about the host IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Android does not natively support video streaming in Android 2.1 or below. What we did was to get the images frame by frame; and break each flame into BYTE[] and send over using `Socket` class. And in receiver's side, we rebuild the images using `BYTE[]` data received.